# Создание файлов через командную строку

Tags: cmd, bat

Имеется код:

```
SET /p a = "Vvedite komandu "
copy nul%a%.txt
help %a%/?>> %a%.txt
```

Задача кода - считывание названия команды командой строки с клавиатуры, создания файла с именем команды и добавить в этот файл справку о команде. Однако после выполнения создаётся безымянный файл с непонятными символами

> (‚лў®¤ бЇа ў®з­ле бўҐ¤Ґ­Ё© ® Є®¬ ­¤ е Windows.
>
> HELP [<Є®¬ ­¤ >]
>
> <Є®¬ ­¤ > - Є®¬ ­¤ , Ё­вҐаҐбгой п Ї®«м§®ў вҐ«п. )

В чём проблема?

Comment: *Задача кода - считывание названия команды командой строки с клавиатуры, создания файла с именем команды и добавить в этот файл справку о команде.* Этот код не может выполнить эту задачу. *В чём проблема?* 1) Неверный код 2) Проблема с кодировкой

Comment: @Akina, 1)В чём конкретно ошибка.?2) Как решить проблему с кодировкой?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, да, в винде. Но с > оно тоже не работает. А с кодировкой я разобрался

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka *>> работает только в Linux* Кто Вам это сказал? наплюйте ему в бороду...

Comment: *В чём конкретно ошибка.?* В чём смысл второй команды? Верен ли синтаксис третьей команды? кстати, если перекодировать полученный текст, сообщение именно об этом и получится. *Как решить проблему с кодировкой?* Например, командой CHCP 1251